# Widgets not saving values

Tags: widgets

I'm filling in the widget values but none of them are saving - I'm new to wordpress so don't know the coding side of things. But no field is working whatever widget I add

Comment: That's not normal behaviour. But without any details it's impossible to know what is going on.

Comment: Usually under the input field there is a blue button you have to click to save the values.

Comment: Do you have Jetpack installed? It may be an issue with 5.2.0: https://jetpack.com/2017/08/02/jetpack-5-2-1-fixes-a-sidebar-widget-bug/